# Is this a one-way or two-way repeated measures anova?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

Can anybody tell me the method written in this paper is a one-way or two-way or possibly three-way repeated measures anova?
"For the main analysis, a 2 * 3 repeated measures ANOVA with Modality and Rhythm type was conducted on percent correct."
In this paper same subjects were undergoing a test composed of two modalities (auditory and visual) and three parts (three rhythms). meaning that all participants underwent all sections.
Any more detail about the method used in this paper is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There were repeated measures on both factors, per your description. Whether the analysis was conducted that way is ambiguous, but my guess would be yes.

Comment: Can you add a link/reference to that paper?